# Subset Pandas Data Frame Based on Some Row Value

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a Pandas data frame with columns that are 'dynamic' (meaning that I don't know what the column names will be until I retrieve the data from the various databases).

The data frame is a single row and looks something like this:

```
    Make   Date        Red     Blue     Green     Black     Yellow     Pink     Silver
89  BMW    2016-10-28  300.0   240.0    2.0       500.0     1.0        1.0      750.0
```

Note that '89' is that particular row in the data frame.

I have the following code:

```
cars_bar_plot = df_cars.loc[(df_cars.Make == 'BMW') & (df_cars.Date == as_of_date)]

cars_bar_plot = cars_bar_plot.replace(0, value=np.nan)

cars_bar_plot = cars_bar_plot.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

This works fine in helping me to create the above-mentioned single-row data frame, **BUT** some of the values in each column are very small (e.g. 1.0 and 2.0) relative to the other values and they are distorting a horizontal bar chart that I'm creating with Matplotlib.  I'd like to get rid of numbers that are smaller than some minimum threshold value (e.g. 3.0).

Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

**The following line of code helps, but does *not* fully solve the problem.**

```
cars_bar_plot = cars_bar_plot.loc[:, (cars_bar_plot >= 3.0).any(axis=0)]
```

The problem is that it's **eliminating unintended columns**.  For example, referencing the original data frame, is it possible to modify this code such that it only removes columns with a value less than 3.0 **to the right** of the "Black" column (under the assumption that we actually want to retain the value of 2.0 in the "Green" column)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get rid of columns or lines? Why don't you just plot each column in a separate bar chart?

Comment: @amyrit - I want to get rid of columns (because I only have one row to begin with).  For example, I have about 30 columns in the data frame.  But, some of the columns have negligible values, so I want to get rid of those and only have values above a certain threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question:

```
lower_threshold = 3.0
start_column = 5
df = df.loc[start_column:, (df >= lower_threshold).any(axis=0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to only keep rows matching your criteria, you can filter you data like this:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x > 0.5).min(axis=1)]
```

i.e. simply look at all values matching your condition, and remove the row as soon if at least one doesn't.

Comment: The actual data frame has about 30 columns and some of the columns have values that are legitimately less than the threshold value that I want to set (e.g. 3.0 or 2.0).  Does your solution apply to **ALL** columns or only to **certain** columns?  Thanks!

Comment: I applied this code: `cars_bar_plot[cars_bar_plot.apply(lambda x: x > 1.0).min(axis=1)]` and found that the **entire row disappeared**.  Did I make a mistake applying this?